# Token pass in new tab - parent tab has the token - need to pass same token to child tab using module federation

Tags: reactjs, webpack, token, federation

I am using the webpack module federation, with in the tab i am able to manage the token between multiple applications, but we have one feature when i click it will open another child tab, need to pass the token instead of parameter.

Is there a way to handle the token between parent and child tab using module federation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.